# How to initialize a C++ Visual Studio VSPackage?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vspackage

I am converting a Visual Studio C++ Command-Line Add-in to a VSPackage. The standard C# VSPackages support an initialize() method but the C++ VSPackage template does not. My VSPackage does not have any UI elements. I am looking for an equivalent to the OnConnection() method in the Add-In (primarily to hook into the SolutionEventSink)

My VSPackage is already auto-loading but how can I *initialize* my C++ VSPackage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All packages implement an IVsPackage interface. The managed package projects (C# and VB.Net) abstracts/hides the actual interface implementation, courtesy of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package class, which provides you with an Initialize() method that is invoked from the underlying IVsPackage.SetSite implementation.

For a C++ package, the IVsPackage::SetSite is actually implemented via the VsSiteBaseImpl template that you inherit through IVsPackageImpl. Looking at that SetSite implementation, I found this little nugget of code:

```
__if_exists(DerivedClass_T::PostSited)
{
    static_cast<DerivedClass_T*>(this)->PostSited(result);
}
```

Which basically says, if you're package class implements PostSited, then call it here. So it appears the answer here is to implement a PostSited method with your VSL/C++ package class, to have a method analogous to the managed Package.Initialize method.

Cheers,

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Thanks!